# Why are underscores used in front of parameters, instead of contract member variables?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, conventions

In Solidity, for example, why:

```
function Greeter(string _greeting) public
{
   greeting = _greeting;
}
```

instead of:

```
function Greeter(string greeting) public
{
   _greeting = greeting;
}
```

The latter appears to be more consistent with other conventions, which borrow from [Hungarian notation:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)

> The notation is sometimes extended in C++ to include the scope of a
>   variable, optionally separated by an underscore.[2][3] This extension
>   is often also used without the Hungarian type-specification:

```
g_nWheels : member of a global namespace, integer
m_nWheels : member of a structure/class, integer
m_wheels, _wheels : member of a structure/class
s_wheels : static member of a class
c_wheels : static member of a function
```